# How to auto create oracle database in Hibernate

Tags: java, spring, oracle, hibernate, spring-boot

I have to create database through hibernate.
As of now with the below properties , ai am auto creating database in mysql.

```
   # YAI DB
   YAIdb.packageToScan=com.sathvik.yae.yai.domain
   YAIdb.maxPoolsize=100
   YAIdb.minPoolsize=10
   YAIdb.driverClassName=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
   YAIdb.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/iat_auto1? 
   createDatabaseIfNotExist=true&amp;serverTimezone=PST
   YAIdb.username=app
   YAIdb.password=app
   YAIdb.Dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
```

How to do it same if i have to create oracle database through Hibernate.